# How do you install Ubuntu in a notebook?

Tags: system-installation

I have a fairly old Asus notebook.
I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and I can not open it because I needed an .ISO opener.
Which one is reliable?
Will that be enough?
Is it the adequate version for a notebook?

Comment: Please, can you tell us precisely what you want to do ? What is the exact model of your notebook, does it can boot from USB or CD-ROM ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a CD-ROM drive on your notebook:

   1.1. Burn a CD-ROM with the ISO configuration. If you don't know how to do it, [click  here](http://www.petri.co.il/how_to_write_iso_files_to_cd.htm)

   1.2. Boot your laptop with the CD generated on pass 1. If your laptop don't recognize  your CD, you should change the BIOS setup. If you don't know how to do it, [click here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm)

   1.3. Before install, click on 'Try before Install' to check if all your hardware is recognized by Ubuntu

   1.4. Be Happy!
2. If you don't have a CD-ROM on your notebook:

   2.1. Copy the ISO to another computer that has a CD-ROM and follow process 1.

Good Luck!